# python - TypeError: invalid file: When trying to make a file a list

Tags: python, list, file

when i run this :

```
    with open(cs, 'r') as f :
    Candidates = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

i get the error :

```
TypeError: invalid file: ['bob', 'john', 'nancy', 'johnnie', 'sam']
```

This seems to be doing the correct thing as it is opening the file 'cs' and putting the values into that string. I saw another tread that said removing the 'r' would fix it, but it didnt work

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: What is the value of `cs`?

Comment: Ensure `cs = "/path/to/file"`.

Answer (score 2):

1. `cs`'s value is `['bob', 'john', 'nancy', 'johnnie', 'sam']`
2. correct filename would be `'cs'` (wrapped with quotes) or a variable of type `str`
3. removing 'r' won't make sense hence it's the default mode